# Python Decimal to string produces strange scientific notation

Tags: python, string, decimal, scientific-notation

I am dealing with a bug where applying the `str` function to an instance of `decimal.Decimal` gives me the string `'0E-1000'`. I expected that `str` applied to a `Decimal` would always give me a string of the form `-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)`, which is what I want.

Firstly, if I understand correctly, the scientific notation `'0E-1000'` represents 0 x 10^-1000, i.e. zero. Why am I getting this particular representation of zero? Why not `'0E-42'`, which is the same?

Secondly, I cannot manually construct a `Decimal` which reproduces this bug. The buggy `Decimal` instance comes from an external source. The expression `str(Decimal(0))` evaluates to `'0'` in the REPL. How can I construct an instance `d` of `Decimal` for which `str(d)` evaluates to `'0E-1000'`?

EDIT: Thirdly, how can I convert an arbitrary `Decimal` instance to a string in, you know, *decimal* notation?

Comment: Where is this number coming from?

Comment: It's coming from a field in a Django model. The field is defined as `models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=1000, blank=True, null=True)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to reproduce your decimal, just construct it from the string:

```
>>> d=decimal.Decimal("0E-1000")
>>> str(d)
'0E-1000'
```

I believe the difference is the difference between `0` and `0.00000` (or in your case 1000 zeros), which is the accuracy. This could be significant in scientific situations, where rounding etc. is controlled by the precision of the operands. If you want to make printing consistent, use [`decimal.Decimal.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize):

```
>>> d=decimal.Decimal("0E-1000")
>>> d
Decimal('0E-1000')
>>> d.normalize()
Decimal('0')
>>> str(d.normalize())
'0'
```

Comment: Ahh, `normalize` helps! Weird. I would expect all normalized Decimals to be normalized automatically. It's quite strange to have to deal with multiple equivalent representations of the same number in the same datatype. (I also have to get my head around this "precision" stuff, which is specified by some hideous global context ...)

Comment: [decimal.localcontext](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext) may keep the global [velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/) away. Just pushes indentation further towards the 80 char PEP8 mark instead...